# What is the longest available version of Once Upon a Time in America?

Tags: alternate-version, once-upon-a-time-in-america

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Once_Upon_a_Time_in_America), the longest available version of *Once Upon a Time in America* is the restored 251-minute one, released in 2012. It was reportedly restored in a 269-minute version, but was then cut down to 251 minutes:

> because of unforeseen rights issues for the deleted scenes, the restoration had a runtime of only 251 minutes. However, Martin Scorsese (whose Film Foundation helped with the restoration) stated that he was helping Leone's children gain the rights to the final 24 minutes of deleted scenes to create a complete restoration of Leone's envisaged 269-minute version. On 3 August 2012, it was reported that after the premiere at Cannes, the restored film was pulled from circulation, pending further restoration work

Apparently, the original Leone's 6-hour version is [somewhere around](https://www.reddit.com/r/criterion/comments/jba61t/its_a_dream_the_6_hour_cut_of_once_upon_a_time_in/). Or [maybe not](https://lostmediaarchive.fandom.com/wiki/Once_Upon_A_Time_In_America_(Found_6-Hour-Long_Print_of_1984_Sergio_Leone_Film)).

So, is *any* version longer than the 251-minute one out in the wild?